# Removing a polygon/circle around a marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I hope you can help.  I have a two pronged problem but I'm pretty new to javascript and the google maps API (v3) so please be gentle.

What i'm trying to do is add a marker to a map based on an address eg. Geocoding, then wherever that marker is, draw a circle around it at a radius of 5km.  I've found some code to do the circle, and also the geocoding and both are working together nicely.

The problem is, I'm wanting to make the marker draggable to a new location and once at the new location, remove the old circle, and draw a new circle.

To understand what i'm trying to achieve, have a look at http://www.gleff.com/test/

With the above example, if you geocode an address, it centers on the marker location and draws the circle.  I want to drag the marker somewhere else, and both remove the old circle, and draw the new circle based on the new location.  At the moment, it just drags the marker to a new location but the circle stays where it is.

I assume the best approach is to drag the marker, then remove the overlay of the circle, and then re-add it at the new location.

Problem 1.  How to remove the circle (overlay)
Problem 2.  How to re-add it at the new location after dragging the marker

I've tried a number of things such as adding markers to an array eg. var markers = [];
 and then trying to clear the overlays using this as an example.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-remove.html

I've been unsuccessful because I'm probably not putting the code in the correct place.

I've experimented with the overlay removal code in multiple parts of the javascript but nothing seems to work.  Rather than go through all the locations of the code i've attempted to add the code to, i've purposely removed all reference to it to make it easier to understand.

So.. Can anyone offer any assistance?  I just want to draw the circle around a marker, and then be able to relocate that marker (including the circle).  But I want to understand how to remove the circle as well because ultimately, I will have multiple markers and will want to remove individual markers (including the circle) permanently from the map.

Note: I'm pretty sure I can work out how to remove the markers themselves, but the circle just doesn't want to be removed.  If I geocode an address twice for example, the circle just draws a second time making it darker, rather than be removed from the map, and re-drawn.

Any assistance would be great.

Thanks
Geoff

Note: The only code i've modified is in the main.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the API but you could have a look at what events are available in the API when you start dragging the marker and also when you drop the marker. Creating event listeners that draw and remove the circle around the marker is the way to go. I'm sorry I can't help you with WHAT event you need to listen for...

Comment: Thanks for that..  I think the more pressing issue is the ability to remove the current circle first.  I've worked out how to trigger the event when the marker is finished being dragged.. In theory anyway.. I haven't had a chance to test the code yet..  eg. the dragend marker event.  I'll listen for that.  At this stage though, I can't seem to work out how to remove the current circle so I can redraw it at the new location.

Comment: Note: I think it will be pretty straight forward to redraw it at the new location.. the hard part is removing the current circle.

Answer (score 0):

This gives a movable marker with circle overlay bound to it

```
function init() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56, -4);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      'zoom': 10,
      'center': mapCenter,
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create a draggable marker which will later on be binded to a Circle overlay.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(56, -4),
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Drag me!'
    });

    // Add a Circle overlay to the map.
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 5000// 5 km
    });
    //Bind circle to marker
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
  }

  // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```